# How to reserve a core on a multi core system completely?

Tags: windows, multithreading, process

I would like to reserve one core for my application. On my searches I could find *dwProcessAffinityMask* to limit my process to run on the cores I want. But this does not
prevent threads of other processes to run on "my" core as well.

Is there a way to disallow a specific core/processor to be used by any (system-wide) process/thread except my process/thread?

Even if it was possible to set the *SystemAffinityMask*, this won't help because this would also prohibit the execution of my process/thread on that processor/core.

Comment: What is that you're trying to achieve? If you just want Hard-RealTime, maybe take a look at realtime systems or additions (such as Xenomai).

Comment: Good hint! But I've placed the **windows** tag on purpose here.

Comment: Not sure how possible this is. The scheduler will decide which thread runs on what core. Unless you can manipulate it, don't see how you can achieve this.

Comment: @Arno But you still didn't state, what do you need it for :)

Comment: You can set processor affinity for a task but, as you said, what you really need is to *remove* processor affinity for all *other* tasks.  I can't imagine that the OS would allow an application to do that for itself.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: I have to have a process of ultimate [Responsiveness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsiveness) running.

Comment: @Arno so I would recommend some ready-made RT solution for windows. There are other aspects than only processor time connected with this.

Comment: @DanPuzey: A `private` hardware resource. `SetThreadIdealProcessorEx` could be a hint, because it gives the scheduler a hint which processor to use, but this would have to be set for all processes (system-wide) and it is not [guaranteed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405517%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: In your app user manual, put 'This application must be run on a computer dedicated to it'.  Alternatively, if you want 'ultimate responsiveness', don't run it on a desktop OS.  There's also the doubt, expressed by others, that what you suggest will actually help any with 'responsiveness'.  If you manage to 'dedicate' one core to your app, I/O interrupts, upper and lower drivers, kernel thread pools etc. would have to run on other cores, so enforcing inter-processor comms for all I/O.  I would regard you request as a 'last gasp' optimization attempt that will probably fail.

Comment: @MartinJames: 'last gasp' is actually true. I was aimimg for `ultimate` and was asking for `affinity` methods in this context. But I now may have to accept that there is no way to do it the way I intended it to do. Thanks for making it clear! Shall I insert a "remove this post vote"?

Comment: You can try to both set the process affinity mask and to boost its priority to `HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS`. You can also periodically walk the process table and "kick off" other processes from YOUR CPU :)

Comment: @Arno - why remove it?  It has some interesting points that may be useful for others.

Comment: @HristoIliev - doing anything like that will use CPU.  I suspect it would be self-defeating:(

Comment: @MartinJames, well, one can monitor the number of context switches in order to detect interference and start the purge only if a certain threshold is met...

Comment: @HristoIliev: Have already investigated all of the priority stuff. "Kick off"? Setting their affinity mask?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to ensure that your process gets to run in a timely manner, just set a high priority for your process (for instance HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS) using [SetPriorityClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Unless the system is running other equally high-priority work (of which there is little on a typical machine), your work will get to run immediately when it's ready to execute.